# how to display an image saved in the database in a drag and drop with laravel 5.8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel

I have this problem, I want to show an image previously saved in my drag and drop, but I have not been able to achieve it ... basically what I want is that when editing a promotion the user can see the image of that promotion and if you wish you can change the image of the promotion
this is my drag an drop zone

```
<div class="form-group row" >
   <div class="file-field input-field" >
      <div class="file-upload">
         <div class="image-upload-wrap">
            <input class="file-upload-input" type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" accept="image/*" name='image' />
            <div class="drag-text">
               <h4>Arrastra y suelta o haz click aqui y selecciona la imagen nueva </h4>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="file-upload-content">
            <img class="file-upload-image" src="#" alt="your image" />
            <div class="image-title-wrap">
            </div>
            <i class="fas fa-times-circle" onclick="removeUpload()" style="color:grey;position: relative;left: -350px;top:-415px;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Eliminar"></i>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

the script of my drag and drop

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {

        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('.image-upload-wrap').hide();

            $('.file-upload-image').attr('src', e.target.result);
            $('.file-upload-content').show();

            $('.image-title').html(input.files[0].name);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

    } else {
        removeUpload();
    }
}

function removeUpload() {
    $('.file-upload-input').replaceWith($('.file-upload-input').clone());
    $('.file-upload-content').hide();
    $('.image-upload-wrap').show();
}
$('.image-upload-wrap').bind('dragover', function () {
    $('.image-upload-wrap').addClass('image-dropping');
});
$('.image-upload-wrap').bind('dragleave', function () {
    $('.image-upload-wrap').removeClass('image-dropping');
});
```

I tried putting the image path in the dropzone img but it didn't work`<img class="file-upload-image" src="{{ asset('uploads/promociones/' .$promociones->imagen_promocion) }}" alt="your image" />`